# root of exponantial equation

Tags: roots, solution-verification

How to find the solution/root of following equation?

$$\sum_{n=1}^N\big(1-e^{-q(n)t}\big) = C$$

where $C$ is constant and $q(n)$ is given, we need to solve the equation for $t$.

Comment: Do you have a reason to believe that there is a closed form expression for general $q$?

Comment: No I don't have any idea

Comment: Do you know _anything_ about $q$, e.g., $q(n) = an + b$ for some real numbers $a$ and $b$, or $q(n) \geq 0$? Is $N$ also fixed?

Comment: Are the $q(n)$ real or complex?  Also, I'm interested to know, where did this problem come from?

Comment: q(n) are real numbers each iteration n has independent different q(n) value. N is fixed real value

Answer (score 1):

If C and q(n) are given, the only way to obtain the solution is numerical. There is no hope that a closed form solution exists. The classical manner would be Newton method, starting at some reasonable value.
Let me consider the case of of N=4 with q(k)=k and C=Pi. Starting with a guess t_old, Newton iterations will write
t_new = t_old - f[t_old] / f'[t_old]
Starting at t_old = 0 will then produce the following iterates : 0.314159, 0.577206, 0.716174, 0.743773, 0.744644, 0.744645. The process can be continued until the desired accuracy is reached.

Comment: Thank you Claude very useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you would like to find a approximate root of the equation.
Assume that t is sufficiently small, use the Tylor Series of $e^x$. 
Then we have the following: 
$$ \begin{align}
1-e^{-q(n)t} &= q(n)t+o(t)  
\end{align}$$
When t is sufficiently small, the higher order term $o(t)$ can be omitted. And then 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^N\big(1-e^{-q(n)t}\big) = C \\
=t \sum_{n=1}^N q(n)
$$
,which implies $$t=\frac{C}{\sum_{n=1}^{N}q(n)}$$

Comment: What you wrote is the very first iterate of Newton method starting at t=0. It is useful but can be very far from the solution (see my answer). Cheers.